# How to remove textbox on each slide?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to remove the page number text box in each slide, created by a 10 years old version of MS PowerPoint, in the following format.

> page 1 of 47

First attempt:

```vb
With ActivePresentation.Slides.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Text = "*/47"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Replace = wdReplaceAll
    .MatchCase = False
End With
```

Second attempt:

```vb
Sub ClNumbers()
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim sTextToFind As String

sTextToFind = "*/47"

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                If InStr(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, sTextToFind) > 0 Then
                    Set oTxtRng = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(InStr(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, sTextToFind), Len(sTextToFind))
                    Debug.Print oTxtRng.Text
                    With oTxtRng
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

How do I remove all page numbers by VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** As far as I know, there is no global find/replace in VBA for Powerpoint. At least there is no `Find`-method for the `Application`-object, the `Presentation`-Object or the `Slides`- or `Shapes` collection. Your attempt 1 fails with a compiler error.

**(2)** Powerpoint doesn't support wildcard or regular expressen search.

**(3)** In your 2nd attempt, you would mark the text in Bold rather than delete the shape or the text of the shape - if it was found (it isn't).

You will need to loop over all shapes of all slides and check if it contains a certain text pattern. You 2nd attempt is close, but the VBA function InStr doesn't work with wildcards either. Instead, you could use the VBA `Like`-operator.

You now need to make up your mind what you want to do with the shapes:
o You can delete them completly with `oSh.Delete`
o You can hide them with `oSh.Visible = False`
o You can just delete the text with `oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Delete`

**(4)** If the shapes are defined on the slide master of the presentation, the code will not do anything as the shapes are not present on the slides at all. In that case, simply edit the slide master in Powerpoint - no code needed.

So your code could look like your 2nd attempt, just modify the inner part (and decide what you want to do)

```
If oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text Like sTextToFind Then
    ' oSh.Delete
    ' oSh.Visible = False
    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, 
(4) is tried in the beginning, the page number is not in the slide master unfortunately.
(3) how can I use like operator to find the text pattern says "page" & * & "of 47".  Please correct my code if it is wrong.  
In fact, I just want to use replace function to remove said text box.  But powerpoint does not accept the * ? # symbol nor allowing us to record a macro...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste the code, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks FunThomas, it works perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
Sub deletepagenumber()
' Remove the page number text box in each slide which was created by old version of MS powerpoint
' Before run this code, please check if the page number could be turned off in the slide master
' Thanks to FunThomas @ stackoverflow
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim sTextToFind As String

' Before run this code, please input the format of the page number, e.g. page ?/47, can be searched as "*/47"
sTextToFind = "*/47"

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text Like sTextToFind Then
                    ' oSh.Delete
                    ' oSh.Visible = False
                     oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```